# Use angular varible in icon chrome extansion

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I try use AngularJS to Change.
There is a script that is after the lapse of time, the icon replaces the chrome extension.
Source:

```
`chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function( alarm ) {
  // 
  console.log("Got an alarm!");
   alert('great1');
   chrome.browserAction.setIcon({ path: "icons/10n.png" });
   chrome.alarms.create({'delayInMinutes': 1});
   location.reload();
});
// 
chrome.alarms.create({'delayInMinutes': 1});
```

The name of the icons stored in the variable {{item.weather[0].icon}}.
But the expression

```
 chrome.browserAction.setIcon({ path:"icons/{{item.weather[0].icon}}.png" });
```

not work.

Angular version

```
    (function(angular){
  'use strict';
angular.module('backskrip',[])
.controller('BackController',['$scope',function($scope){
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm) {
  // события по будильнику.
  console.log("Got an alarm!");
   alert('great1');
   chrome.browserAction.setIcon({ path: "icons/{{vm.data.list[0].weather[0].icon}}.png" });
   chrome.alarms.create({'delayInMinutes': 1});
   location.reload();
});

// создаем будильник
chrome.alarms.create({'delayInMinutes': 1});
}]);
})(window.angular);
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background/content/popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: You [asked a question about this a week ago](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41079721/3773011), which is now closed.  The correct way to handle such situations is to edit that question such that it is clear what you are asking, and provide a *complete* [MCVE]. Once the question is answerable and on-topic, that question can be re-opened. You should *not* just ask a new question. While this question is better than the prior one, it still does not provide us everything needed to duplicate the problem (i.e. a **[mcve]** and the other information I mentioned in my previous comment).